# Techniques for computing fundamental units in cubic extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are there any slick ways of computing the fundamental unit for the cubic polynomial of the form $X^3+aX+b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? The simplest example would be $X^3+X-1$, where a root $\alpha$ is a unit with inverse $\alpha^2+1$. What about the general cubic of this form?

There's one example in Milne's Algebraic Number Theory notes, but the method only works for a some cubics of this form. Some people I talked to suggested finding the regulator, but that doesn't seem much easier either as I don't see how this would be accessible through anything but the zeta-function.

Comment: If you google for some combination of the words "cubic", "fundamental", "unit", and "algorithm", you will see that there is an enormous amount of literature on this.

Answer (score 10):

See for example, section V.3 of Frölich & Taylor's *Algebraic number theory*, or section 13.6 of Alaca & Wiliams' *Introductory algebraic number theory*. The general cubic case was done by Voronoi and is (allegedly, as I haven't checked myself) covered in Delone & Fadeev's *The theory of irrationalities of the third degree*.

Comment: A more general description of the idea of Voronoi's algorithm can be found in Buchmann: A Generalization of Voronoi's Unit Algorithm I and II. J. Number Theory 20 (1985), no. 2, 177--209.

Answer (score 10):

Use Artin's inequality: if $K$ is a cubic field with one real embedding and $v > 1$ is a unit in $O_K$ then $|\text{disc}(K)| < 4v^3 + 24$. (I use inequalities on elements of $K$ via the one real embedding of $K$.) The proof of Artin's inequality is a pain. As a corollary, if $u > 1$ is a unit in $O_K$ and $4u^{3/2} + 24 < |\text{disc}(K)|$ then $u$ must be the fundamental unit of $O_K$. (Proof: Let $\varepsilon > 1$ be a fundamental unit, so $u = \varepsilon^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. If $n \geq 2$ then Artin's inequality with $v = \varepsilon$ implies $|\text{disc}(K)| < 4\varepsilon^3 + 24 = 4u^{3/n} + 24 \leq 4u^{3/2} + 24$, which contradicts the hypothesis of the corollary and also *explains* where the hypothesis comes from.)

Example: $K = {\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, so $|\text{disc}(K)| = 108$. A unit in $O_K$ is $\sqrt[3]{2}-1$, which is between 0 and 1. Its reciprocal is $u := 1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}$. Numerically, $4u^{3/2} + 24$ is around 54.1, which is less than 108, so $u$ is a fundamental unit of $O_K$.

Example: $K = {\mathbf Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^3 +\alpha - 1 = 0$. Then $|\text{disc}(K)| = 31$. 
The unique real root of $X^3 + X - 1$ is around .68, so less than 1. Its reciprocal 
will be a unit greater than 1. If we identify the real root of $X^3 + X - 1$ with $\alpha$ then $u := 1/\alpha = \alpha^2 + 1$ is a unit greater than 1 in $O_K$. From a computer, 
$4u^{3/2} + 24$ is around 31.096, which is *greater* than $|\text{disc}(K)| = 31$, so it looks like we can't use Artin's inequality to deduce that $u$ is the fundamental unit. However, you could modify the corollary to show $u$ is no worse than the square of a fundamental unit and then check $u$ is not a square in $O_K$ by showing it isn't a square mod $\mathfrak p$ for some prime $\mathfrak p$ in $O_K$. That would prove $u$ is a fundamental unit of $O_K$.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to cover most cases I can come up with. I'll also take a look at Voronoi's algorithm.

Comment: dstt: One basic example where it seems to be impossible to make this method work (even with a modification like the one I use in the second example) is the cubic field Q(a) where a^3 - a - 1 = 0. This field has discriminant 23, which is less than 24, and thus it is hopeless to get an inequality of the form 4u^{3/n} + 24 < |disc(Q(a))| for any unit u > 1 and positive integer n at all. 

Comment: I should say in the previous comment that the absolute value of the discriminant of that field is 23. The actual discriminant is -23.

Answer (score 7):

If you want algorithms, check the sources by Voronoi and Buchmann already mentioned, or Cohen's books. If you're satisfied with a method, the following works very well in extensions of small degree and small discriminant. Let $\omega$ be a root of your polynomial and compute lots of norms of elements $a+b\omega$ as well as their prime 
factorization. Then use linear algebra to eliminate the prime ideals, and you will get a unit $\eta$ (possibly not fundamental). For example, if (say)
$(1+3\omega) = {\mathfrak p}_1{\mathfrak q}_1$, 
$(3-\omega)  = {\mathfrak p}_1$ and $(4+7\omega) = {\mathfrak p}_1{\mathfrak q}_1^2$,
then the element $(1+3\omega)^2/(3-\omega)(4+7\omega)$ will be a unit.

If you can find a prime ideal such that $\eta \bmod {\mathfrak p}$ is not a square (cube, 5th power) etc, then $\eta$ will not be a power. In the last pages of Artin's notes on algebraic number theory you can find an estimate for cubic fields that shows you how far you will have to go.